# Weird locking resulting in deadlock

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where tables are being locked in a way that I don't understand after reading the mysql doc.

I am running mysql `8.0.26` with innodb.

I can set up a test case like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `deadlock_test` (
    `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `value` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `value` (`value`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I'll then populate this table with a single value

```sql
INSERT INTO deadlock_test (value) values ('test');
```

I then start 3 transactions

```sql
start transaction; -- tx1
start transaction; -- tx2
start transaction; -- tx3
```

I start by having tx1 attempt to insert a value that will conflict on the unique key

```sql
INSERT INTO deadlock_test (value) values ('test'); -- tx1
```

Running `SELECT * FROM performance_schema.data_locks` shows me

```
| transcation_id | index_name | lock_type | lock_mode | lock_status|       lock_data      |
|----------------|------------|-----------|-----------|------------|----------------------|
|       1        |    NULL    |   TABLE   |    IX     |   GRANTED  |        NULL          |
|       1        |    value   |   RECORD  |    S      |   GRANTED  |     'test', 1        |
|       1        |  PRIMARY   |   RECORD  |    X      |   GRANTED  |supremum pseudo-record|
```

From reading the doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html under the section `INSERT` it says

> If a duplicate-key error occurs, a shared lock on the duplicate index record is set.

At this point i'm already confused. I understand the IX lock on the table, and I understand the shared (S) lock on the conflicting record (as the doc says), but why is it applying a next-key lock on the supremum pseudo-record? The doc explicitly states under `INSERT` that:

> INSERT sets an exclusive lock on the inserted row. This lock is an index-record lock, **not a next-key lock** (that is, there is no gap lock) and does not prevent other sessions from inserting into the gap before the inserted row.

I was expecting it to lock the ID of the conflicting record, not the supremum.

This now prevents any other values being inserted into the table until tx1 commits.
If tx2 and tx3 attempt to insert the same records into the table:

```sql
INSERT INTO deadlock_test (value) values ('test'); --tx2
INSERT INTO deadlock_test (value) values ('test'); --tx3
```

both of these records are now waiting on tx1 to commit for their `INSERT INTENTION` locks

```
| transcation_id | index_name | lock_type |      lock_mode   | lock_status|       lock_data      |
|----------------|------------|-----------|------------------|------------|----------------------|
|       3        |    NULL    |   TABLE   |         IX       |   GRANTED  |        NULL          |
|       3        |  PRIMARY   |   RECORD  |X,INSERT_INTENTION|   WAITING  |supremum pseudo-record|
|       2        |    NULL    |   TABLE   |        IX        |   GRANTED  |        NULL          |
|       2        |  PRIMARY   |   RECORD  |X,INSERT_INTENTION|   WAITING  |supremum pseudo-record|
|       1        |    NULL    |   TABLE   |        IX        |   GRANTED  |        NULL          |
|       1        |    value   |   RECORD  |        S         |   GRANTED  |     'test', 1        |
|       1        |  PRIMARY   |   RECORD  |        X         |   GRANTED  |supremum pseudo-record|
```

If tx1 now commits

```sql
commit; --tx1
```

both tx2 and tx3 are given their locks on the supremum-psuedo record

```
| transcation_id | index_name | lock_type |      lock_mode   | lock_status|       lock_data      |
|----------------|------------|-----------|------------------|------------|----------------------|
|       3        |    NULL    |   TABLE   |         IX       |   GRANTED  |        NULL          |
|       3        |  PRIMARY   |   RECORD  |X,INSERT_INTENTION|   GRANTED  |supremum pseudo-record|
|       3        |    value   |   RECORD  |         S        |   GRANTED  |    'test', 1         |
|       3        |  PRIMARY   |   RECORD  |         X        |   GRANTED  |supremum pseudo-record|
|       2        |    NULL    |   TABLE   |         IX       |   GRANTED  |        NULL          |
|       2        |  PRIMARY   |   RECORD  |X,INSERT_INTENTION|   GRANTED  |supremum pseudo-record|
|       2        |    value   |   RECORD  |         S        |   GRANTED  |    'test', 1         |
|       2        |  PRIMARY   |   RECORD  |         X        |   GRANTED  |supremum pseudo-record|
```

I'm confused here again, how can an exclusive next-key lock be granted to both of these transactions? Surely it should only be given to the first and the second should have to wait.

Because now i'm in a situation where neither of these transactions can insert anything into the table as they are each waiting on each other.
Performing an attempted insert on tx2 like

```sql
INSERT INTO deadlock_test (value) values ('new value')
```

Now if either of these remaining 2 transactions attempt to insert anything into this table they are not going to be able to as they are waiting on the exclusive next-key lock

```
| transcation_id | index_name | lock_type |      lock_mode   | lock_status|       lock_data      |
|----------------|------------|-----------|------------------|------------|----------------------|
|       3        |    NULL    |   TABLE   |         IX       |   GRANTED  |        NULL          |
|       3        |  PRIMARY   |   RECORD  |X,INSERT_INTENTION|   GRANTED  |supremum pseudo-record|
|       3        |    value   |   RECORD  |         S        |   GRANTED  |    'test', 1         |
|       3        |  PRIMARY   |   RECORD  |         X        |   GRANTED  |supremum pseudo-record|
|       2        |    NULL    |   TABLE   |         IX       |   GRANTED  |        NULL          |
|       2        |  PRIMARY   |   RECORD  |X,INSERT_INTENTION|   GRANTED  |supremum pseudo-record|
|       2        |    value   |   RECORD  |         S        |   GRANTED  |    'test', 1         |
|       2        |  PRIMARY   |   RECORD  |         X        |   GRANTED  |supremum pseudo-record|
|       2        |  PRIMARY   |   RECORD  |X,INSERT_INTENTION|   WAITING  |supremum pseudo-record|
```

and finally at this point if tx3 attempts to insert any record into the table we arrive at a deadlock.

The doc does mention deadlocks as a possibility when duplicate key conflicts arrise but it only shows examples that involve things like deletes or rollbacks, whereas I am using nothing but inserts.

I feel like I'm definitely misunderstanding something about the expected process here and would very much appreciate it if someone could enlighten me.

Comment: There is no difference between a commit and rollback for transaction 1 as it cannot do any modifications. When commited or rolled back, transaction 2 and 3 are already at a deadlock

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for the clarification, that makes sense now. That feels like it makes unique constraints almost useless. 
If as little as 3 concurrent requests involving something as simple as basic single insert statements result in an almost guaranteed deadlock then how could anyone use them in ernest? 
I've been using them as protection against duplicates in the face of concurrency but this scenario is making me think that may have been a terrible idea.

Comment: I think you are oveestimating the chances of having three concurrent transactions wanting to insert the same piece of data into a unique column

Comment: 'next-key', 'supremum', 'auto-inc with no higher value' -- these sound similar.  Change your test case to have (at least) and id=2 row; the results may be more understandable.

Comment: @RickJames I tried adding 5 initial records to the table (test1, test2, test3, test4, test5) and used test3 (id=3) in the insert statements. Is that what you meant? The data_locks look identical after making those changes outside of the obvious replacements you'd expect for inserting different data.

Comment: @Wodlo - Oh, well.  Are you just trying to understand locking?  Or is this some realistic application?  I would _guess_ that the locking mechanism focused on "realistic" test cases and your test case fell by the wayside.  ("Realistic" = not having multiple threads trying to insert the same data at the same time.)

Comment: @RickJames Unfortunately this is actually causing issues in an application I'm working on - I am basically extracting entities from news articles. I've already taken steps to ensure different processes don't work on the same article, but it is still possible for different articles to contain the same entities. In reality the transactions do more than just insert one record and therefore last longer than in this example.

Comment: @RickJames I think what i'll end up doing is trying to catch as many duplicates as I can with a simple SELECT statement, maybe trying to commit earlier and more often at the cost of atomic-ness and then finally adding in some kind of delayed re-try to cases that still deadlock. It just came as a surprise to me that unique constraints are so fragile. I was relying on them quite heavily